# How to call a collection parameterized method in a class from main()

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing java program with collections (ArrayList). I've a doubt in function call from main(). Because the function is having ArrayList object as parameter. How to create a functioncall for collection parameters for a method?

### MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     SecondClass obj = new SecondClass();
     obj.func();
     obj.func2(??????);//receives arraylist obj as parameter and print the values of that object
     }
}
```

### SecondClass.java

```
class SecondClass{
   List<classname> func(){
      List<classname> result = new ArrayList<classname>();
       ...
       ..
       return result;
      }
   void func2(List<classname> result){
       //how to print the 'result'

       //for( classname  results: result) {
       //   System.out.println(results);
       //}
   }

}
```

How to call the func2() from main() and print the List object 'result'?

Comment: Well, presumably you want to assign the result of `obj.func()` to a variable; then, just pass that variable as a parameter to `func2`.

Comment: Remember that in `java` you have `methods`. Not `functions`.

Comment: @xenteros - Is that distinction relevant/meaningful in practice?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth imo yes. For the same reason you don't start method names with capital letters. They mess up.

Comment: I´d also say, if `func2` only prints the `List` and is not bound to the instance itself, making the method `static` would make more sense in my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     SecondClass obj = new SecondClass();
List<classname> listObj = obj.func();
     obj.func2(listObj);//receives arraylist obj as parameter and print the values of that object
     }
}
```

Over here the `listObj` is filled with the value returned from the method `func`.So the same can be passed as a parameter to `func2`.

Comment: You should explain your answer, rather than just dumping some code.

Comment: I'm sry Andy, My code length is high. But my doubt is this only. all other codes r correct. I just don't know to call the function. Now it works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

```
   public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     SecondClass obj = new SecondClass();

    List <classname> listOfSecondClass= obj.func();
     obj.func2(listOfSecondClass);
     }
}
```

Comment: why did you removed my answer ?

Comment: By seeing your reputation score, I know that you are expert in programming.. But my 1st response is coming from Nilesh. I should honor him. Same time you also provide the answer. So I personally thank u.. Nice to talk to u..